# Prevent a user going to a certain page until condition met in vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, vue-router

I am using vue with rails. I am a agents table with fields name, address, verified. I want to prevent the logged in user to go to the homepage unless user is verified. verified is a boolean field in user tab. Below is how my router.js file looks. I am not able to figureout to do this.

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
import Axios from 'axios';
import MyProfile from 'views/profile.vue';
import HomePage from 'views/homepage.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
 { 'path': '/homepage', component: HomePage },
 { 'path': '/views/profile', component: MyProfile, meta: { requiresAuth: true }},
]
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    axios.get('/verified.json')
      .then(function() {
        if (to.path === '/loginin' || to.path === '/changepassword') {
          next('/');
          return;
        }
        next();
      })
      .catch(function() {
        if (to.path.match(/views/)) {
          next('/');
          return;
        }
        next();
      });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: what's api response if user isn't verified? Maybe it returns 'false' and then you don't meet condition in the catch block

Comment: @DavidGo ya that is what I want. if the user isn't verified it shouldn't be able to meet the condition in the catch block.

Comment: So what exactly your api says if user isn't verified?

Comment: @DavidGo it returns verified: false

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears to execute `next` no matter the outcome of the verification, i see some go to `root` but the one that matters runs `next`.

I assume `catch` is handling a 4xx forbidden response, if that's the case then the call to `next();` is allowing unwanted continuation, either delete `next()` in `cache` to make the user stay where they are or change it to `next('/')` or some other path to redirect them to a permission issue or something.

I would delete `next` to make the user stay where they are and display a permission denied popup.

```js
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

    axios.get('/verified.json')
      .then(function() {

        // Not sure why you need this, login and change password would not
        // have requiresAuth meta on them so this could would never run?
        if (to.path === '/loginin' || to.path === '/changepassword') {
          next('/');
          return;
        }

        // User allowed to continue.
        next();

      })
      .catch(function() {

        // If viewing /views the user is allowed to continue bypass requiresAuth?
        // again if views route does not have requiresAuth meta this will never
        // get called
        if (to.path.match(/views/)) {
          next('/');
          return;
        }

        // Use not permitted, omit call to next() user stays on current page...
        alert('Permission Denied')

      });
  }
  else {
    // requiresAuth not set (public access)
    next();
  }
});
```

I think it is wiser to do this:

```js
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {

  if (to.meta.hasOwnProperty('requiresAuth') && to.meta.requiresAuth === true) {

    axios.get('/verified.json')
      .then(function() {

        // ALLOW TO CONTINUE
        next();

      })
      .catch(function() {

        // DISALLOW CONTINUE
        // Use not permitted, omit call to next() user stays on current page...
        alert('Permission Denied')

      });


    return
  }


  // ALLOW TO CONTINUE
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking if user not verified in the `catch` block, move it to `then`. Catch block will meet the condition if the api call had some error. Example code would be:

```
     .then(res => !res.data.verified && to.path.match(/views/)
                  ? next('/')
                  : next()
          )
     .catch(e => console.log(e))
```